# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm developing an ionic3-app and got the following error when trying to add and student in a form:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

I tried with "Elvis" variable putting ? in the data binding but didn't work.

How can I reference the input to de subject attributes?

Each subject has "nombre", "estudios", "cuatrimestre", "tipo" atributtes, all strings instead of cuatrimestre that is a number

the typescript code is:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SubjectProvider} from '../../providers/subject/subject';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-addsubject',
  templateUrl: 'addsubject.html',
})
export class AddsubjectPage {

  subject: { nombre:'', estudios: '', cuatrimestre: '', tipo: ''};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public subjectRest: SubjectProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AddsubjectPage');
  }

  saveSubject() {
    this.subjectRest.saveSubject(this.subject).then((result) => {
     //const id = result['_id'];
      //this.router.navigate(['/subject-details', id]);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

}
```

and the respective html code is:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Añadir asignatura</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Añadir Asignatura</h2>
  <form (ngSubmit)="saveSubject()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Nombre</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="subject.nombre" name="nombre"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Nombre</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="subject.estudios" name="estudios"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Cuatrimestre</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" required [(ngModel)]="subject.cuatrimestre" name="cuatrimestre"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Tipo</ion-label>
      <ion-select type="text"  required [(ngModel)]="subject.tipo" name="tipo">
        <ion-option value="Obligatoria">Obligatoria</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Optativa">Optativa</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block>Añadir asignatura</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score -1):

The subject variable initial value is undefined. In the constructor give it a value.

```
this.subject = {
    nombre: '',
    estudios: '',
    ...
}
```